# How do I forcibly ovewrite a local repo with changes from a remote repo while still preserving history?

Tags: git, git-pull

I know that if I want to forcibly overwrite a local repo with files from a remote repo, I do this:

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
```

The problem with this is that when I go to look at the history of the local repo, it has completely obliterated the history and replaced it with a carbon copy of the history of the remote repo.

Is there a way I can do this forcible overwrite while still preserving the history?

For example, if I have a file in the local repo with the following content:

```
- ContentA
- ContentB
- ContentC
```

And I have the same file in the remote repo with the following content:

```
- ContentA
- ContentC
- ContentD
```

After the pull from the remote repo, I want the history to show this for the file:

```
Version #1
- ContentA
- ContentB
- ContentC

Version #2
- ContentA
- ContentC
- ContentD
```

I don't want it to show this (from a forcible overwrite):

```
Version #1
- ContentA
- ContentC
- ContentD
```

Nor do I want it to show this (from a merge):

```
Version #1
- ContentA
- ContentB
- ContentC

Version #2
- ContentA
- ContentB
- ContentC
- ContentD
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You might look at defining your own custom git merge driver.

Comment: Also, your reset --hard to origin/master moves your local master to that commit, so I would think you just lost your work there. Sounds like you want to merge, but in a special way. I just wonder if you aren't using git in the way everyone else does, because you can easily see both versions with git. Normally people dont want to concatenate the files when they bring them together. They want to combine them in a merge manner.

Comment: You could rebase the remote onto the local, or you could pull remote into a separate branch then reset --soft, stash and pop, or cherry pick individual commits from the remote.

Comment: @DavidN, you're kind of right - I want to merge, but I want the remote repo to replace whatever changes I made. Thinking about it, I guess I could just do git fetch followed by git merge origin/master --no-commit --no-ff, then I could manually merge and force all the remote repo content over what's in local, but this is potentially time consuming. :(

Comment: ok, sorry, I reread your posting and wasnt understanding what you wanted to do.

Comment: Yes, you cant have the remote doing a merge for you. You need to do the the merge and then you push to it what you have and it just fast forwards up to your commit. So you need to arrange your commits to resolve whatever you want and then push that.

Comment: You can do a merge with a --no-commit option and then pick which side's files you want with a git checkout --ours or git checkout --theirs, then git add those files and finally git commit to conclude the merge, to select which of the file changes you want. As for the history that you want, well you get to edit the actual commit comments, if thats what you want.

Comment: OK, that will work, I guess. Can you post this as an answer so that I can mark it and you can get some points?

Comment: done. thanks for remembering about the upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have the remote do a merge for you. You need to do the the merge and then you push to it what you have and it just fast forwards up to your commit. So you need to arrange your commits to resolve whatever you want it to look like and then push that

You can do a merge with a --no-commit option and then pick which side's files you want with a git checkout --ours or git checkout --theirs, then git add those files and finally git commit to conclude the merge, to select which of the file changes you want. As for the history that you want, well you get to edit the actual commit comments, if thats what you want.

Comment: You can merge with `--strategy ours` or `--strategy theirs` instead of going to the trouble of a no-commit merge, if you want to do the same thing across the whole repo.

Comment: I think thats -X ours or -X theirs, when --strategy is recursive (which is the default strategy.